# c++ passing function to function

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I've got
class funciton Find. This function have to accept some variables and sometimes (pointer to) another function which will be used inside. How I should declare it?

```
class CRoute
{
...
list<_T> Find(_T u1, _T u2, ????){
   if (????) {...}
}
...
}
```

have to accept:

```
X.Find ( "Wien", "Berlin" );
X.Find ( "Wien", "Munchen", TrainFilterCompany ( set<string> { "CD", "DB" } ) );
X.Find ( "Wien", "Munchen", TrainFilterSpeed ( 120, 200 ) );
X.Find ( "Wien", "Munchen", [] ( const CTrain & x ) { return x . m_Company == "CD"; } );
```

(funtions returns bool)

(_T in this case is string)

Comment: I don't know if there's a better way, but I make a typedef for the function pointer and use that.

Comment: Give this a read: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members

Comment: You probably want `std::function<>`.

Comment: Wait a sec. Totally forgot this is 2016. [Use `std::function`.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) AKA what he ^ said.

Comment: Take a look at the [C++ standard algorithm library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm), look at how they handle passing "predicates" to functions.

Comment: FYI: `_T` Identifiers that begin with a single underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved. You're not allowed to use them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a template method taking any callable object (which would support lambdas with captures as well as passing in a reference to an external function):

```
template <typename Filter>
list<_T> Find(_T u1, _T u2, Filter filter) {
    if (filter(obj)) ...
}

// Overload taking no filter and returning everything
list<_T> Find(_T u1, _T u2) {
    return Find(u1, u2, [](const CTrain&) -> bool { return true; });
}
```

You can also use something like `std::function<bool (const CTrain&)>`.  This would incur a slight overhead of a dynamic allocation when passing in a callable object, but it wouldn't result in code explosion if the Find method is particularly complex.

Comment: template <typename Filter>
list<_T> Find(_T u1, _T u2, Filter filter) works well but I have declare it second time list<_T> Find(_T u1, _T u2)  (because I need 3-rd function just sometimes)  any solution like  foo( int a, int b = 0) ?

Comment: @Dmitriy No, I don't think there's really any way to specify a default type and argument in a templated argument.  However, you could at least reuse the general templated version in the two-argument overload - will edit my answer as the original question did specify it has to accept `x.Find("Wien", "Berlin");`